# Print a picture of a web application in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, printing

Hello I have my web application but I want to give the possibility to download and Printer-friendly image attached to a form, I have no idea how to do because I'm obviously new to C # and asp.net . As I can start ?

i try with onserverclick but i don´t have idea with i do to communicate with printer is my question How communicate with printers controllers to print a image?

I implemented the following and I get an error with the printer, but I do not get no window available printers.

```
 protected void imprime_tiff(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pqr);
        pd.Print();
    }


    void pqr(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\MaxImage\\Desktop\\firma6.png");
        Point p = new Point(100, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, p);
    }
```

and in my html i put the next

```
 <button name="printButton" id="printButton" type="button" class="btn btn-  default" onserverclick=" imprime_tiff" runat="server" >
                                Imprime
  </button>
```

Comment: There's two basic approaches. The first is client side and therefore has nothing to do with ASP.NET and is related to the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The other option is to create a printable file on the server (such as a PDF, XPS, or Word document) and provide that to the client. You should pick your approach, and state which one you want to use in your question, otherwise your question runs the risk of being too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to interact directly with the printer from a web browser. `PrintDocument` is only for WinForms applications and won't work with web applications.

The client browser needs to trigger the printing either manually (File > Print...) or through interaction with the page such as clicking on a button after which you can trigger the print dialog using JavaScript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print

You can control the rendering of your page to make it "printer friendly" using a print style-sheet, there is a thorough write up here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/